# Send Ring Command to Bluetooth Headset using Android 2.2 SDK

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth

I'm trying to send a RING Command to my Bluetooth Headset using Android 2.2 SDK (to simulate a fake phone call, just to initiate a SCO audio channel). I've read through the BluetoothChat example from google, but i dont think I can use it for AT Commands and such. I've also looked through BluetoothAdapter and BluetoothSocket. Can someone point me to a sample or in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no public APIs to do this.
The Bluetooth Chat uses the SPP (Serial Port Profile) profile , but you need access to the HeadSet / HandsFree Profile (HSP or HFP) , these profiles are used during calls and AT commands for RING etc gets sent over them.

Comment: Is there a way to gain access to programmatically interact with the HS or HSP profiles?

Comment: not for what you are trying .. refer to the APIs here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html

Comment: Is it possible to send a command to the HS or HSP profile without the API then?

Comment: @TheSteve: Hi.. were you able to achieve this? If yes, can you help me with this? I'm trying to do the same for gingerbread.